# How to find all $m_i$ such that $M=m_1 + 2 m_2 + 3 m_3 + 4 m_4$?

Tags: combinatorics

Given some positive integer $M\in\Bbb N$, I want to compute a sum of some function $f(m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4)$ over all $m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4$ with the restriction that $m_1 + 2 m_2 + 3 m_3 + 4 m_4=M$, with $m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4 \in \Bbb N$. Spelled out, this reads something like
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4; m_1 + 2 m_2 + 3 m_3 + 4 m_4=M}}f(m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4) .
\end{align}
The question is how can I evaluate this sum in a meaningful way? And how can I find/specify the quadruplets $(m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4)$ for which $m_1 + 2 m_2 + 3 m_3 + 4 m_4=M$ holds in a closed expression, for example to implement the sum on a computer?

What I tried is to write out the first few possibilities and find a pattern, but I was not able to do so successfully. I also tried to look for solutions for even and odd values of $m_1$ separately, however also without much success.

And is there maybe some general formula for all n-tuples $(m_1,m_2,...,m_n)$ such that $M=\sum_{i=1}^n i m_i$?

Comment: What is your convention for $\Bbb N?$ Does it include $0?$

Comment: No it does not, all integers are assumed to be strictly positive

Comment: It is related to Bell polynomials and Faa de Bruno formula, so you can try to consider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are looking for all $(x,y,z,t)\in\Bbb N^4$ such that $x+2y+3z+4t=M.$ Eliminating successively $x,y,z,t,$ the conditions become:
$$1\le x=M-2y-3z-4t,$$
$$2\le 2y\le M-3z-4t-1,$$
$$3\le3z\le M-4t-3,$$
$$4\le4t\le M-6,$$
so that your sum is
$$\sum_{t=1}^{\lfloor\frac{M-6}4\rfloor}\sum_{z=1}^{\lfloor\frac{M-4t-3}3\rfloor}\sum_{y=1}^{\lfloor\frac{M-3z-4t-1}2\rfloor}f(M-2y-3z-4t,y,z,t).$$

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer!